# Draw a rotating circle over previous canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation, geometry

I'm trying to draw a rotating circle over another canvas.

I've managed to draw the circle, but once it rotates it fills everything inside the rotating radius white and the circle becomes a big continuous circle.

I just want a small circle rotating around the canvas center like a planet around the sun.

This is just example code in my real code the red rectangle is a roulette wheel that rotates in the opposite direction this is the reason why I have two canvas.

I need the (ball) to be white this is why I tried to use .fillstyle and fill() but it doesn't works how I want.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    #container { position: relative; }
    .canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
  </style>
  <div id = 'container'>
    <canvas class = "canvas" id= "rectangleCanvas" width = "500" height= "500" style = "z-index : 1" ></canvas>
    <canvas class = "canvas" id= "ballCanvas" width = "500" height= "500" style = "z-index : 2"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function drawRectangle(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById("rectangleCanvas")
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
    };
    drawRectangle();
    function drawBall(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById("ballCanvas");
      if(canvas.getContext){
        ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx2.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx2.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx2.translate(250,250);
        ctx2.rotate(Math.PI / -180);
        ctx2.translate(-250, -250);
        ctx2.arc(250,65,10,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx2.stroke();
        ctx2.fill();
      }
    }
    setInterval(drawBall,5);
  </script>
</body>
```

Can somebody help please?

Comment: Besides your problem: 1) use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of `setInterval` for canvas drawing; 2) cache the result of `canvas.getContext("2d")` so the browser doesn't need to query the DOM everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert

```
ctx2.beginPath();
```

before the ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

Comment: Well that was easy :-) thank you very much. I still have a lot to learn about drawing with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to redraw the recrangle each step of the timer. This is how canvas works.